# Entendendo o conceito de Threads na prática (em Python)

Tags: python

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def carrinho(velocidade,nome):
    distancia = 0
    while distancia <= 1000:
        print("Carrinho :",nome,distancia)
        distancia += velocidade
        time.sleep(0.3)



carrinho1 = Thread(target=carrinho,args=[1.1,"Ed"])
carrinho2 = Thread(target=carrinho,args=[1.2,"Paulo"])


carrinho1.start()
carrinho2.start()
```

Estou tentando entender o conceito de Threads. Fiz um programa que tenta simular a corrida de dois carros de forma que eles pareçam correr juntos. Eles precisam percorrer 1000 metros.

Existe uma maneira diferente de fazer? Mais simples?

Comment: Funciona! Eu rodei aqui!

Comment: time.sleep(0.3) é para ficar mais lenta a alternancia entre os "carros" e assim vermos melhor.

Comment: É difícil entender o que está sendo perguntado aqui. Seria mais interessante você dizer que problema quer resolver para que possamos avaliar sua solução ou sugerir outra.

Comment: Fiz um programa que tenta simular a corrida de dois carros de forma que eles pareçam correr juntos. Eles precisam percorrer 1000 metros.

Existe uma maneira melhor de fazer? Mais simples?

Comment: Maneira "melhor" vai ser subjetivo (e vc corre o risco de ter a pergunta fechada como baseada em opinião). Mais simples vai depender do ponto de vista (em termos de linhas de código? em termos de compreensão do funcionamento? em termos de tempo de execução?). Eu sugeriria você aproveitar a visibilidade da sua recompensa editando a pergunta para deixar clara a sua dúvida. Ela parece ser mais no sentido de "Por que os carros parecem correr juntos, se estão em threads separadas?". Ou seja, foque nessa dúvida.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, eu gostaria de ver uma outra maneira de fazer a mesma coisa, usando threads

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, obrigado pela sugestão.Editei a pergunta!

Comment: do meu ponto de vista, o código já está totalmente simples. O que talvez poderia ajudar talvez seriam outros exemplos com threads.

Comment: Eu respondi, tentando aproveitar o seu exemplo para explicar o conceito de threads. Talvez ajude.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Threads são linhas de execução concorrentes em um mesmo processo (no seu caso, o seu programa em Python). Elas são concorrentes no sentido de que executam simultaneamente, mas cada um com a sua própria linha de execução - quase como se fossem programas diferentes. A distinção é que programas diferentes são de fato diferentes: cada um tem sua própria área de memória e a comunicação entre eles não é tão simples (embora seja possível por diversos métodos, tais como Sockets, Pipes, Shared Memories, etc). Threads, por outro lado, executam dentro de um mesmo processo, então elas podem compartilhar memória diretamente (e aí, você precisa tomar certos cuidados, como utilizar semáforos para garantir a ordem de acesso aos dados e evitar corrupção - uma thread escrevendo enquanto outra lê).

Em um computador com apenas uma CPU, *não há mágica*: as threads não executam *realmente* ao mesmo tempo. O sistema operacional (SO) fica encarregado por "escalonar" as threads para permitir que todas executem um pouco de cada vez, gerando a sensação (ou o resultado prático) de que elas parecem ser simultâneas. Assim, o SO deixa a thread A executar um pouquinho, depois passa o controle para a thread B executar um pouquinho, e depois volta pra thread A, e assim por diante... E é por isso que no caso de compartilhar memória e usar semáforos (note que *não é* o caso do seu programa de exemplo, que é bem simples) é preciso tomar cuidado também com situações de bloqueio (pode ser que a thread A fique parada esperando a thread B liberar um recurso, enquanto a thread B está parada esperando a thread A liberar outro recurso - o que gera um [deadlock](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) que trava o seu programa todo). Por outro lado, em um computador com mais do que uma CPU, as threads podem ser executadas simultaneamente: uma em cada CPU disponível e livre. Os problemas de concorrência citados ainda podem existir, mas há um desempenho melhor porque o SO tem mais facilidade em realizar o escalonamento (que ainda precisa ocorrer).

Bom, no seu programa há duas threads que executam **a mesma função**. Logo, elas fazem a exata mesma coisa e por isso tendem a demorar o mesmo tempo em cada período de escalonamento. Supondo um computador com uma só CPU, o SO sabe que pode passar o controle do único processador para outra thread quando uma delas para de processar pra fazer algo envolvendo o hardware ou simplesmente esperando, por exemplo. Logo, quando uma de suas threads faz um `print`, o tempo em que a impressão demora para acontecer no hardware a thread não está fazendo nada, e o SO passa o controle do processador único para a outra thread executar. O mesmo acontece quando ela faz o `sleep`.

Como as suas duas threads fazem a mesma coisa, o resultado tende a ser bem alternado (as vezes a ordem se inverte, mas sempre há execuções "pares" das duas threads), tal como você experimentou:

```
Carrinho : Ed 0
Carrinho : Paulo 0
Carrinho : Paulo 1.2
Carrinho : Ed 1.1
Carrinho : Ed 2.2
Carrinho : Paulo 2.4
Carrinho : Ed 3.3000000000000003
Carrinho : Paulo 3.5999999999999996
Carrinho : Paulo 4.8
Carrinho : Ed 4.4
Carrinho : Ed 5.5
Carrinho : Paulo 6.0
Carrinho : Ed 6.6
Carrinho : Paulo 7.2
Carrinho : Ed 7.699999999999999
Carrinho : Paulo 8.4
Carrinho : Ed 8.799999999999999
Carrinho : Paulo 9.6
Carrinho : Ed 9.899999999999999
Carrinho : Paulo 10.799999999999999
Carrinho : Ed 10.999999999999998
Carrinho : Paulo 11.999999999999998
Carrinho : Ed 12.099999999999998
Carrinho : Paulo 13.199999999999998
Carrinho : Ed 13.199999999999998
Carrinho : Paulo 14.399999999999997
Carrinho : Ed 14.299999999999997
Carrinho : Paulo 15.599999999999996
Carrinho : Ed 15.399999999999997
Carrinho : Paulo 16.799999999999997
Carrinho : Ed 16.499999999999996
Carrinho : Paulo 17.999999999999996
Carrinho : Ed 17.599999999999998
Carrinho : Paulo 19.199999999999996
Carrinho : Ed 18.7
Carrinho : Paulo 20.399999999999995
Carrinho : Ed 19.8
Carrinho : Paulo 21.599999999999994
Carrinho : Ed 20.900000000000002
```

Porém, experimente remover completamente a linha com o comando `time.sleep(0.3)` e redirecionar a saída para um arquivo texto (execute `programa.py > teste.txt`, por exemplo). Então, veja o resultado final (ele vai executar muito rapidamente e você não vai ver nada, pois o resultado estará dentro do arquivo texto). Será algo do tipo:

```
Carrinho : Ed 0
Carrinho : Ed 1.1
Carrinho : Ed 2.2
Carrinho : Ed 3.3000000000000003
Carrinho : Ed 4.4
Carrinho : Ed 5.5
Carrinho : Ed 6.6
Carrinho : Ed 7.699999999999999
Carrinho : Ed 8.799999999999999
Carrinho : Ed 9.899999999999999
Carrinho : Ed 10.999999999999998
Carrinho : Ed 12.099999999999998
Carrinho : Ed 13.199999999999998
Carrinho : Ed 14.299999999999997
Carrinho : Ed 15.399999999999997
Carrinho : Ed 16.499999999999996
Carrinho : Ed 17.599999999999998
Carrinho : Ed 18.7
Carrinho : Ed 19.8
Carrinho : Ed 20.900000000000002
. . .
Carrinho : Paulo 0
Carrinho : Paulo 1.2
Carrinho : Paulo 2.4
Carrinho : Paulo 3.5999999999999996
Carrinho : Paulo 4.8
Carrinho : Paulo 6.0
Carrinho : Paulo 7.2
Carrinho : Paulo 8.4
Carrinho : Paulo 9.6
Carrinho : Paulo 10.799999999999999
Carrinho : Paulo 11.999999999999998
Carrinho : Paulo 13.199999999999998
Carrinho : Paulo 14.399999999999997
Carrinho : Paulo 15.599999999999996
Carrinho : Paulo 16.799999999999997
Carrinho : Paulo 17.999999999999996
Carrinho : Paulo 19.199999999999996
Carrinho : Paulo 20.399999999999995
```

Note como a primeira thread praticamente imprimiu todo o seu trabalho antes de a impressão da segunda thread produzir seus resultados. Isso ocorre porque a escrita em arquivo é consideravelmente mais rápida do que a escrita na tela, e assim a thread que começou primeiro (Ed) dá menos oportunidade para o sistema operacional escalonar entre ela e a outra. Esse resultado foi da execução do programa no meu computador, que dispõe de 8 núcleos de processamento (8 CPUs). Não havia mais nada rodando, de forma que as demais CPUs estavam certamente ociosas. O [colega @Caffé comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/entendendo-o-conceito-de-threads-na-pr%c3%a1tica-em-python/148111?noredirect=1#comment306782_148111) que isso pode se dever a alguma dificuldade do Python em redistribuir threads entre os processadores, o que talvez seja verdade. Mas talvez o processamento das threads tenha sido tão rápido que o SO não teve tempo hábil para realizar qualquer escalonamento.

O fato é que, independentemente de se ter um ou mais CPUs disponíveis, não há como garantir exatamente a ordem em que as threads serão escalonadas, pois isso fica a cargo do SO. Alguns SOs e linguagens permitem a definição de prioridades, mas ainda assim a escolha fica a cargo do SO.

Desse modo, se você deseja realmente simular os carros correndo em um mesmo *enquadramento de tempo*, é mais comum utilizar *uma só thread* e cuidar você mesmo do escalonamento das "tarefas".

É o que jogos, por exemplo, costumam fazer. Você executa em um intervalo de tempo previamente estabelecido (controlando o tempo de cada "quadro" da animação, tal como se fosse no cinema) e executa o passo de iteração de cada instância de carro, que pode ser implementado via Orientação a Objetos, por exemplo.

O enquadramento do tempo é feito da seguinte forma. Suponha que você deseja que cada passo de interação dure aproximadamente 30 milisegundos (essa é meramente uma escolha arbitrária para exemplificação; não estou dizendo que é a melhor ou mais correta escolha - isso depende de outras questões que não vêm ao caso agora). No passo do laço (`while`), você faz:

- Executa `Ed->move()` e conta o tempo que essa chamada leva para processar.
- Desconta o tempo processado de 30 milisegundos. Guarda em uma variável `t`.
- Executa `Paulo->move()` e conta o tempo que essa chamada leva para processar.
- Desconta o tempo processado do tempo na variável `t`.
- Se sobrou algum tempo na variável `t`, é sinal de que as chamadas foram muito rápidas. Logo, você chama `sleep` com o que sobrou em `t` para aguardar o restante e assim totalizar os 30 milisegundos. Se não sobrou nada, você não chama `sleep`, pois esse "quadro" tem que acabar imediatamente para tentar compensar o tempo gasto pelo movimento dos carros.

> Nota final: observe que independentemente do que foi discutido acima,
>   os seus carros se movem com velocidades distintas. O primeiro carro
>   aumenta o espaço no "tempo" em 10% a cada interação, enquanto que o
>   segundo carro aumenta o espaço no tempo em 20%<sup>*</sup>. O ponto-chave dessa
>   explicação é que para garantir que esse movimento seja mais próximo de
>   real, você precisa garantir que os intervalos de tempo de interação
>   para cada carro sejam sempre os mesmos. Talvez isso já esteja fugindo
>   da sua preocupação com entendimento de "threads", mas eu achei que era
>   útil explicar. :)
>
> <sup>*</sup> Na verdade o incremento de velocidade é fixo em 1.1 ou 1.2 porque
>   você usa `+=`. O incremento seria percentual como descrito se você utilizasse
>   `*=`.

Comment: Gostaria de uma implementação simples usando concurrent.futures. Mas sua resposta já vale a recompensa!

Comment: você conseguiria me mostrar uma implementação com concurrent.futures?

Comment: Rapaz, eu não costumo programar muito em Python (sou mais de C++ mesmo rs). Assim, eu nem sei direito como funciona o concurrent.features, pra ser sincero. :p De todas as formas, pelo que a documentação descreve ("*The concurrent.futures module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables.*"), trata-se de implementação de execução concorrente **assíncrona**. Ou seja, a "característica" do escalonamento vai acontecer da mesma forma. Talvez você até possa "agendar" as atualizações dos carros apropriadamente, mas não seria usar um canhão pra matar formiga?

Comment: Eu estou aprendendo python ainda! Para mim, ver vários exemplos ajuda muito no aprendizado, por isso fiz a pergunta. Sua resposta está excelente e vale uma recompensa maior! Vou só aguardar para ver se alguém consegueria me mostrar uma implementacao com concurrent.futures!

Comment: Ah, obrigado novamente. Mas como vc pode perceber, eu já tenho bastante reputação. Sinceramente, não respondi pela recompensa. Se alguém mais responder, fique bem tranquilo para escolher a resposta que você quiser. :) E eu entendo que está aprendendo, mas assim, note que esse site não é um fórum. Se a sua pergunta ficar mudando de foco, o conteúdo não se torna mais tão útil. Você é bem vindo a abrir novas perguntas, entretanto!

Comment: Eu agradeço muito mesmo sua atenção! São pessoas como você que fazem o stackoverflow um otimo lugar para se aprender! Sou muito grato!

Comment: E são comentários como esse último que valem muito mais do que qualquer reputação. :) []s

Comment: Tem duas perguntas em aberto que eu estou curioso para aprender. Se puder ajudar, serei grato. Mas se não puder, já fico satisfeito com toda a ajuda que me deu com a sua maravilhosa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146991/criando-um-arping
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147823/como-criar-um-port-scanner-tcp-usando-o-m%C3%A9todo-syn-tcp-syn

Comment: @EdS veja esta pergunta/respostas, tem um exemplo com `concurrent.futures`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146417/fibonacci-com-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-paralelo-threads/146450

Comment: @Miguel,obrigado pelo link!

Comment: Luiz Vieira, se o computador tem mais de uma CPU, não pode ocorrer a distribuição das threads entre diferentes CPUs de modo a realmente ter algum trabalho executado em paralelo ou "ao mesmo tempo"? Aparentemente, o python tem limitações quanto a distribuir threads entre processadores, o que pode ter causado este resultado de processamento "serial" na sua experiência salvando para arquivo mesmo você tendo mais de um core na sua máquina...

Comment: @Caffé Sim, de fato, se o computador tiver mais de uma CPU a execução em paralelo realmente ocorre (se tiver GPU também, dependendo da implementação/recurso). Mas eu suponho que ainda assim o SO precise direcionar as threads às CPUs, de modo que algum escalonamento (inicial) ainda ocorre. No exemplo, tudo provavelmente acontece tão rápido que não deve dar tempo ou folga para esse escalonamento acontecer (o meu PC tem 8 CPUs). Assim, não sei realmente afirmar se é limitação do Python ou característica do problema (apostaria mais nessa). Essa me parece outra pergunta interessante a ser feita. :)

Comment: Basicamente, estou questionando a parte da sua resposta que diz que nada acontece realmente ao mesmo tempo. Pelo que entendo, hardware e sistema operacional permitem que múltiplas threads de um mesmo processo executem sim operações ao mesmo tempo. O custo de distribuição e sincronização sempre vai acontecer, mas desde que temos mais de uma CPU, se a linguagem não tiver restrições, podemos ter trabalho acontecendo realmente em paralelo em vez de termos apenas uma distribuição forjada pelo SO do tempo de uma CPU entre diferentes threads.

Comment: @Caffé Atualizei a resposta conforme os seus questionamentos. Valeu!

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, sua resposta foi fantástica! Obrigado. Ajudará muitas pessoas!