# Como implementar Fibonacci de forma mais eficiente usando dicionários?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Uma implementação de Fibonacci recursiva é:

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return F(n-1)+F(n-2)
```

O problema é que é um pouco ineficiente, uma vez que, por exemplo, para calcularmos F(5), calculamos mais de uma vez F(3). Ouvi falar que a implementação com dicionários sería mais eficiente. Como implementar Fibonacci de forma mais eficiente usando dicionários?

Comment: Retirei a minha resposta porque vi queres continuar a optar pela recursividade, e ela na realidade não te ajudou nesse aspeto.

Comment: @Miguel:   eu gostei da sua resposta! Se puder voltar...

Answer (score 5):

Você está num caminho certo de tentar não recalcular uma função recursiva várias vezes quando seu resultado não muda, mas o jeito mais fácil e mais eficiente não é usar dicionários; é usar o [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

O `lru_cache` é um decorador que automaticamente guarda o resultado da sua função num cache. Quer dizer, a primeira vez que você chama uma função, como ele ainda não guardou o resultado, ele tem que calculá-la. Daí ele te retorna o resultado e guarda esse resultado no cache, uma memória interna. A partir da segunda vez em que você chama a função com os mesmos argumentos, como ele já tem o resultado guardado, ele te retorna o resultado imediatamente sem recalcular a função.

O resultado de usar o cache é bem dramático. Veja a comparação de fazer cálculos de `fib(0)` até `fib(40)`, na minha máquina, com exatamente a mesma função e só botando ou tirando o `lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time

@lru_cache(maxsize=64)
def fib_com_cache(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib_com_cache(n-1) + fib_com_cache(n-2)

def fib_sem_cache(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib_sem_cache(n-1) + fib_sem_cache(n-2)


def fib_ate_40(funcao):

    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    for j in range(40):
        funcao(j)
    return time.perf_counter() - t1

# Primeiro fazemos fib até 40 sem cache
print('Tempo de execução sem cache: {:.6f} segundos'.format(fib_ate_40(fib_sem_cache)))

# Em seguida, fazemos com cache
print('Tempo de execução com cache: {:.6f} segundos'.format(fib_ate_40(fib_com_cache)))
```

Resultado:

```
Tempo de execução sem cache: 71.009936 segundos
Tempo de execução com cache: 0.000053 segundos
```

Bastou adicionar o decorador `@lru_cache` pra ganhar um aumento tremendo de performance. Isso é útil para todas as funções em que o resultado, ao chamar a função com os mesmos argumentos, não muda (quer dizer, ela não depende de estado externo) e quando for chamada muitas vezes com os mesmos argumentos, e/ou quando o cálculo da função for pesado.

Como guardar resultados consome memória, você pode especificar quantos resultados quer guardar em memória no máximo (é o parâmetro `maxsize`). Quando o número de valores armazenados passa do `maxsize` dado (padrão 128), então o menos recentemente usado é descartado (daí o LRU: é de "Least Recently Used").

Se sua função depender de estado externo que muda raramente ou você por algum outro motivo precisar eliminar esses valores armazenados, basta chamar `cache_clear`:

```
fib_com_cache.cache_clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

Não percebi bem o que queres dizer com "implementar com dicionários", mas aqui está uma maneira iterativa que é muito mais rápida:

```
def F(n): 
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n): 
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a
```

Talvez com dicionários queiras fazer:

```
dic = {20: F(20), 10: F(10)}
```

[DEMONSTRACÃO](https://ideone.com/ECiBDX)

Caso queiras continuar a implementar a versão recursiva acho que a resposta do Pedro resolve bem o problema.

[Relacionado (Fibonaci com threads, calculando para vários valores ao mesmo tempo)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146417/fibonacci-com-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-paralelo-threads)

Comment: os dicionários seriam para guardar os valores e não ter que chamar toda hora a função F. Assim, não precisaria recalcular sempre os mesmos Fibs

Comment: @EdS desta maneira não calculas o Fib para o mesmo valor mais que uma vez quando chamas `F`. Neste exemplo, depois tens os valores de `F(20)` e `F(10)` guardados, podes usa-los como quiseres