# Como fazer uma chamada de sistema paralela no python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou querendo executar um programa paralelamente ao meu, no caso se chama `download.py`, ele deve executar independente da minha execução principal `main.py`, mas deve ser chamada no mesmo. Pensei em fazer chamada de sistemas e estou usando o `subprocess`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
 ...
 path = '/home/prisvo/view_admin/backend/update_article/download.py'         
 process = subprocess.call(['python', path], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
 ...
```

Porém, quero continuar com a execução do código normalmente, a execução do `download.py` demora um pouco, mas não posso esperar a execução. Existe alguma função do `Subprocess` ou outra biblioteca que consiga fazer isto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar [`threads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) para executar processos em pararelo.

Vou colocar aqui o exemplo mais simples consoante o código que forneceste:

```
import threading
import time # por motivos de demonstracao

def download(): # codigo relativo ao download
    # path = '/home/prisvo/view_admin/backend/update_article/download.py'         
    # process = subprocess.call(['python', path], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    time.sleep(5) # so por demo
    print('download acabou')

threading.Thread(target=download).start() # iniciar o processo em paralelo
# continuar o resto da logica
print('aqui o codigo continua')
print('aqui tambem')
print('e aqui também')
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/PeachpuffCulturedGlobalarrays)

**Nota**: neste exemplo eu não espero qualquer retorno da funcao `download`, se tivesse de trabalhar sobre alguma coisa que pudesse retornar da função teria de estruturar de maneira um pouco diferente ([`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146417/fibonacci-com-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-paralelo-threads/146450#146450))