# Execução de funções simultaneamente em Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um trecho de um código que realiza o "text to speech", porem para ver a função print() eu tenho que aguardar a função playsound() terminar. Existe alguma maneira que faça o script executar a função print() enquanto a playsound() está sendo reproduzida? Criar um objeto?

```
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

#Funcao responsavel por falar 
def cria_audio(audio):
    tts = gTTS(audio,lang='pt-br')
    #Salva o arquivo de audio
    tts.save('hello.mp3')
    #Da play ao audio
    playsound('hello.mp3')
    print("Seu áudio está sendo reproduzido.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existi sim, tudo que voce precisa fazer é criar uma nova thread:

```
import threading
import time

def thread_function(name):
  print("Thread {}: Comecando".format(name))
  time.sleep(3)
  print("Thread {}: Terminando".format(name))

x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
print("Main: Antes da thread comecar a executar")
x.start()
print("Main: Continuando")
print("Main: Tudo pronto")
```

Execute o código acima e você terá como saida:

```
Main: Antes da thread comecar a executar
Thread 1: Comecando
Main: Continuando
Main: Tudo pronto
Thread 1: Terminando
```

Perceba que o código chega no ultimo print antes da função `thread_function` terminar de executar. Logo tudo que voce precisa fazer é rodar a função `playsound` em uma thread diferente. Nesse código acima eu simulei o audio sendo tocado com a função `sleep`.

Uma thread é basicamente um processo que será executado em paralelo ao programa principal para saber mais sobre threads e como usa-las em python recomendo as seguintes referencias:

[explicação de threads no stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/entendendo-o-conceito-de-threads-na-pr%C3%A1tica-em-python)

[thread in python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

[Aprofundando em thread em python](http://recologia.com.br/2015/07/programacao-multi-thread-em-python/)

Esse assunto é um assunto muito interessante e tão complexo o quanto você quiser se aprofundar mas se você está querendo se tornar um melhor desenvolver recomendo muito estudar mais sobre o assunto de programação multi-thread.